# Убрать из get запроса yii2 activeForm название модели

Tags: php, yii2, yii, get

Есть форма ActiveForm, неважно какая модель, какой контроллер. Просто когда я отправляю простой Get запрос получается - `https://site.ru/search?Tag%5Bname%5D=content` Не использовать activeform нельзя! как убрать из гет запроса название модели и остальные лишние элементы и привести все к нормальному виду, как - https://site.ru/search?name=content

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'method' => 'get',
    'action'=>['/search'],
    'id' => 'form-comment',
]); ?>


<?= $form->field($model, 'name')->widget(TypeaheadBasic::classname(), [
'data' => $data,
'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Поиск...', 'autocomplete' => 'off'],
'pluginOptions' => ['highlight'=>true],
])->label(false);
?>

<button>поиск</button>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Comment: Можно посмотреть в сторону urlManager

Answer (score 0):

Переопределите `Tag::formName()` чтобы он возвращал пустую строку:

```
public function formName()
{
    return '';
}
```

После этого параметры будут без упоминания модели `https://site.ru/search?name=content`